# colorbox not resizing correctly

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm just displaying one image in a colorbox.

[image]

As you can see here, I even took care to set a height/width for the image. But the colorbox wrapper doesn't set the correct height, it uses a wrong height (20px).

What's with that?

It only happens for some users, I don't get this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting an `innerHeight` value when you initialize the colorbox:

```
$(element).colorbox({
    innerHeight: 529
});
```